# Angular js applying Gradients with ng style

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Unable to set gradients using angular js ng-style directive.. able to set normal color by using below

```
<span ng-style="{'background-color': slidercolor}">works</span>
```

But for gradient it doesnt work

Below is the jsfiddle for the same.

```
<span ng-style="{'background-color':'-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-    stop(0%,'slidercolor'), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,0)))'}">didnt work</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sT8ar/1/

Also please let me know which should be enclosed in quotes and which should not..

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: this one should work on ie10: http://jsfiddle.net/sT8ar/2/

Comment: the issue is most browsers require different code to display a gradient, what you have is meant for webkit browsers only, like chrome and safari.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got two problems here:

1. `-webkit-gradient()` produces `<image>`, not `<color>`, it shoud be used as `background-image`.
2. In Angular expression concatenation is done with a `+` (plus sign).

So the correct syntax is ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sT8ar/4/)):

```
<span ng-style="{'background-image':'-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,   color-stop(0%,'+ slidercolor+'), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,0)))'}">
  Works now too.
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you.

**controller**

```js
private setStyles() {
  const rgbaGradientStart = hexToRgba(this.hexGradientStart, 1);
  const rgbaGradientEnd = hexToRgba(this.hexGradientEnd, 0.1);
  const gradientParams = `left, ${rgbaGradientStart} 0%, ${rgbaGradientEnd} 50%`;

  this.gradientStyles = {
    'background-image': `-webkit-linear-gradient(${gradientParams})`,
    // 'background-image': `-moz-linear-gradient(${gradientParams})`,
    // 'background-image': `-o-linear-gradient(${gradientParams})`,
    // 'background-image': `-ms-linear-gradient(${gradientParams})`,
    // 'background-image': `linear-gradient(${gradientParams})`,
  }
}
```

**template**

```html
<div
  class="super-gradient"
  [ngStyle]="gradientStyles"
></div>
```

P.S.: you may also be interested in this
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11362#issuecomment-244816438